# make a div resizable using mouse in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to implement resizable div like this but in react->   http://jsfiddle.net/T4St6/82/

```
<div id="container">
<div id="left_panel"> left content! </div>
<div id="right_panel">
    <div id="drag"></div> right content!
</div>
```

I tried using css property (resize-horizontal) which works fine, but it comes on the right bottom and not on right border.
Is there a way to implement without using any library?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it for this purpose. [react-resize-panel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-resize-panel)

Comment: I don't want to use any external package for this. Can we simply use css/js ?